# how to auto-fill an object in java?

Tags: java, pojo

i have a simple pojo

```
class animal{

private String name;

animal(String name){
 this.name = name;}

private Features features;

private int max_life;

//
*
* other properties and their getter's and setter's
*//
}
```

so now once i initialize the name of the POJO with any `name` i want the rest of the attributes to auto fill.

eg: `animal("cat")` should auto-fill other attributes such as `max_life` and `features` based on a cat.

is there any property's file or any way that will detect the initialization and auto fill them with pre-defined properties??

Comment: I'd initialize default values in the constructor

Comment: how would that work for other values eg: dog, mouse??

Comment: `if (name == "cat") { ... } else if (name == "dog") { ... } else if (name == "mouse") { ... }`?

Comment: to many if else, seeing i can have many values for which default values might be required.

Comment: Use a switch statement or define an abstract class/interface. You're asking for a better way to do something that doesn't really have a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can actually think of several ways to implement such thing. But what you’re looking for is a *factory*.

The idea is: the factory receives the animal kind, and creates the instance based on the kind.

In general, the most basic (although terrible) example is:

```
public class AnimalFactory {
    public Animal create(String name) {
        if (name.equals(“cat”)) {
            return new Animal(...);
        }
    // other
    }
}
```

You may then create animals as such:

```
AnimalFactory factory = new AnimalFactory();
Animal kitty = factory.create(“cat”);
```

This can be done in multiple ways and improved in many aspects. Read more about the *Factory design pattern*.

Answer (score 4):

You have some options:

1 - Initializing in the constructor

```
class Animal {

   private String maxLife;
    
   public Animal (String name) {
      switch(name) {
         case "cat":
            maxLife = 10;
            break;
         case "dog":
            maxLife = 20;
            break;
         default:
           maxLife = 1;
      }
   }
}
```

2 - Using Inheritance:

```
abstract class Animal {
   String name;
   int maxLife;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  public Cat() {
     maxLife = 10;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  public Dog() {
     maxLife = 20;
  }
}
```

3 - Using a factory (with classes of option 2):

```
class AnimalFactory {
   
   public static Animal create(String name) {
       switch(name) {
         case "cat":
            return new Cat();
         case "dog":
            return new Dog();
      }
   }

}
```

Also, in Java, the convention is to use CamelCase. For classes, it should be capitalized and for variables/fields should start with lowercase.

Comment: Your first example should include `break` statements after each case.

Comment: thanks, just did. the idea of the 'solution' remains the same :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called Podam which helps in auto filling a Pojo. I provide below the link.

https://mtedone.github.io/podam/

To quote from the link, you have to use like this.

```
// Simplest scenario. Will delegate to Podam all decisions
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();

// This will use constructor with minimum arguments and
// then setters to populate POJO
Pojo myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(Pojo.class);

// This will use constructor with maximum arguments and
// then setters to populate POJO
Pojo myPojo2 = factory.manufacturePojoWithFullData(Pojo.class);

// If object instance is already available,
// Podam can fill it with random data
Pojo myPojo3 = MyFactory.getPojoInstance();
factory.populatePojo(myPojo3);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [Factory Design Pattern](https://www.javatpoint.com/factory-method-design-pattern) for this, possibly in combination with [Strategy Design Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strategy-pattern-set-1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal{

private String name;

  Animal(String name)
  {
     this.name = name;
     switch(name){
        case "cat":
           this.features = new Features("cat");
           this.max_life = 16;
           break;
        case "dog":
           this.features = new Features("dog");
           this.max_life = 15;
           break;
        default:
           this.features = new Features("unknown");
           this.max_life = 0;
           break;
     }

  }

  private Features features;

  private int max_life;

//
*
* other properties and their getter's and setter's
*//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), which I would recommend, you could also consider using the [Prototype Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).